# DatasetAutoFolds' object has no attribute 'global_mean' on python surprise

Tags: python, recommendation-engine

I'm using surprise to perform a cross validation

```
def cross_v(data, folds=5):
    algorithms = (SVD, KNNBasic, KNNWithMeans, NormalPredictor)
    measures = ['RMSE', 'MAE']

for a in algorithms:
    data.split(folds);
    algo = a();
    algo.fit(data)
```

I call the function this way

```
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
multiple_cv(data)
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pac1/prueba.py", line 30, in <module>
    multiple_cv(data)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/pac1/prueba.py", line 19, in multiple_cv
    algo.fit(data)
  File "surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.pyx", line 155, in surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization.SVD.fit
  File "surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.pyx", line 204, in surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization.SVD.sgd
AttributeError: 'DatasetAutoFolds' object has no attribute 'global_mean'
```

I missed something??

Answer (score 22):

[As per the docs](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/trainset.html), the input to the fit method must be a Trainset, which is different from a Dataset, that you are trying to use. You can split a Dataset to a Trainset (and Testset) using the output of the split method as mentioned [here](http://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#use-cross-validation-iterators).

In your example,

```
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
```

Then, you can use

```
algo.fit(trainset)
```

The Trainset and the Testset thus obtained can be used as the inputs for fit and test functions respectively.